# What is the difference between Average Square Error and Mean Square Error and does lower ASE / MSE mean a better model?

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression

[this is the result of original model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6I4ua.png)
[image]

[this my 2nd model after variable transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqcax.png)

[image]

Comment: This isn't a SAS question, it's a statistical question and belongs on Cross Validated instead.

Answer (score -1):

Formally in statistics there are three measures of central tendency: mean, median, and mode. Among the general population, the word "average" is commonly used for the specific statistics term "mean". This is why these two terms have the same value in your images. Most statistics software will not use both of these words to represent the same value so that there is no confusion.